# IPython auto completion is calling __getattr__

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

thanks for taking the time to read this. Hope everything is alright with you on these strange times.

I'm implementing a class and started looking how to provide auto-completion on its attributes.
From my research online i reached the conclusion that ipython completions come from the `__dir__` method.

`__getattr__` is normally called when you access an attribute that doesn't exist. In my project if that happens, an operation that takes a while runs. Why is ipython trying to access the attributes instead of just displaying what `__dir__` returned?

In cell 2 i hit tab after the dot to ask for completions.

[image]

Comment: This isn't specific to iPython; `__getattr__` appears to be called on the last item of the list returned by `__dir__`, even in CPython.

Comment: Just checked, its being called on every element of `__dir__`

Comment: I'm not sure. You may want to dig into the [`rlcompleter` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/rlcompleter.html#module-rlcompleter), which CPython (and possibly iPython) uses to enable tab completion. The module comments explicitly mention the risk of `__getattr__` being invoked, though it's not obvious to me *how* that happens.

Comment: It's really strange. I'll investigate this.

Comment: if you can paste your snippets as code, instead of images, more people will be able to copy and paste your tests and help you.
(BTW, it is not only a good idea - it is the law around here)

Comment: Now, onto your problem: regardless of the particular behavior of iPython, it is not a good design to have a long running operation to be trigered with `getattr` - precisely for this motive: it may be requested when you don't expect.

There are several ways to design around this, one of them is to have your code designed as a property. Or, you could timestamp the moment `__dir__` is called, and make `__getattr__` NOT to perform the lengthy task if `__dir__` was called in the last, say "0.1" seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you need an instance of your class. Those methods are instance methods.

I added logging for easier debugging. I am getting output in the `ipython` console when I `example.something` or `example.<tab>`.

- Python version 3.8.2
- IPython version 7.14.0

This is my observation: On `<tab>` `__dir__` is called and the returned collection of items are displayed in IPython console. If the item chosen after `<tab>` is not an attribute of the object, then `__getattr__` is called in an attempt to look it up.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        logging.info("init")
        self._attrs = ("foo", "bar", "baz")
        for attr in self._attrs:
            setattr(self, attr, attr)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        logging.info(f"__getattr__ called: {attr}")

    def __dir__(self):
        logging.info("__dir__ called")
        return ("extra", *self._attrs)


# Create an instance of Example.
# The instance methods can then be called on the instance.
example = Example()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info(example)
```

[image]

Comment: My bad, i forgot to create the object. I edited already. I used sleep because print wont be displayed while ipython is calling the method. That's why in your code it seems the problem is gone. If you add a sleep you can see that auto complete is calling the `__getattr__`.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thank you. I could have sworn I was seeing some output with `print`. Now I am not.

Comment: It didn't solved the problem. Like i said, if you add the sleep to your code and try to auto complete it will take 2 seconds. My problem is with auto completion calling the __getattr__. I forgot to instantiate the object in my example, but that's not my problem.

Comment: Is your expectation that `__getattr__` be called when the tab key is hit? From my observation the `__dir__` method is called when tab key is hit.

Comment: The `__dir__` is being called, and that's what i expect. What i don't get, and what i presented as my problem is that `__getattr__` is also being called when it shouldn't. You can verify it by adding the sleep. When you hit tab, it will call dir (what i want) but then it calls getattr that should only be called when you access an attribute. And auto complete should not be accessing the attribute. That was written in my question. Please review the question.

Comment: There is no evidence that `sleep` is being called. I experience a significant delay sometimes in ipython when I use the tab key without calling `sleep`. I'm trying to figure out a way to properly debug this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213104/discussion-between-dmmfll-and-andre-alves).

Comment: On my jupyter notebook errors will be ignored so the only way i found was to add a sleep. If you need evidence that it is being called, add a big sleep, then remove it. You'll see the difference.

Comment: I will add that I have run into this exact same issue in Jupyter notebooks. I have attributes that are loaded in a separate thread and dynamically attached. Auto complete works great until I mess with __getattr__ and add a waiting loop for the attribute to finish loading. When I do this, the autocomplete is blocked on this wait.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a workaround for this. Provided that you know the attribute name that takes a long time, only do the custom **getattr** code when that attribute name is passed, else just raise an attribute error. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Following from your comment to one of the answers:

> The `__dir__` is being called, and that's what i expect. What i don't
> get, and what i presented as my problem is that `__getattr__` is also
> being called when it shouldn't. You can verify it by adding the sleep.
> When you hit tab, it will call dir (what i want) but then it calls
> getattr that should only be called when you access an attribute. And
> auto complete should not be accessing the attribute.

What happens is that iPython will call `__getattr__` for the names listed in `dir` that  it does not "see" in the instance: it wants to assert the member exists.

I think the most correct thing there would be not to trigger a lenghty task with `__getattr__` alone - but require a call, after you require the attribute. I understand that might not be the best for your design, but that would be simple - if your `__getattr__` code is similar to this:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name == "special_name":
        # long task
        do_things()
        do_more_things()
        result = finish_processing()
        return result
    ...
```

Change that for:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name == "special_name":
        def inner_func():
            # long task
            do_things()
            do_more_things()
            result = finish_processing()
            return result
        return inner_func
```

This way, instead of `example.attribute` to get your lengthy task executed, you will need to use `example.attribute()`.

Now - to keep things as they are, with no need for calling the attribute, a nice workaround, if you have control over both `__dir__` and `__getattr__` is, like I said in a comment to the question, to create a mechanism to detect the usage in interactive mode, and skip calling the long task in that case.
Typically iPython will call first `__dir__` and then `__getattr__` in a short sequence - so you can have an instance attribute to check that timing, and just return "None" (to signal iPython the attribute actually exists):

```
 import time

...

class Example:
    ...

    def __dir__(self):
        self._dir_called_at = time.time()
        ...

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        dir_called_at = getattr(self, "_dir_called_at", 0)
        if time.time() - dir_called_at < 0.1:  # Suggestion: 0.1 seconds, you may have to tweak this
            return None
        ...
        if name == "special_name":
            # long task
            do_things()
            do_more_things()
            result = finish_processing()
            return result
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today (2023 May) with jupyter notebook.
I found the solution proposed by chrisjsewell on Github in this [comment](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12828#issuecomment-902991224) to work well for me.

The auto-completing should work if you add the KeyError exception treatment, e.g.,

```
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            do_what_you_want_with_key
        except KeyError:
            # or other errors that may occur
            raise AttributeError(key)
```